# Display latest orders on WooCommerce "My account" Dashboard

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders

I'm trying to show customer last 3 orders on WooCommerce dashboard. But `get_template()` does not work at all and shows nothing.

I also tried to put `orders.php` form table in to the `dashboard.php` template file but It displays no orders here, while already I have some active orders. I'm so confused and have no idea about this problem.

This is my dashboard code:

```
<?php get_header();?>

<?php

 * @see     https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @package WooCommerce\Templates
 * @version 4.4.0
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly.
}

$allowed_html = array(
    'a' => array(
        'href' => array(),
    ),
);
?>

<p>
    <!-- <?php
    printf(
        /* translators: 1: user display name 2: logout url */
        wp_kses( __( 'Hello %1$s (not %1$s? <a href="%2$s">Log out</a>)', 'woocommerce' ), $allowed_html ),
        '<strong>' . esc_html( $current_user->display_name ) . '</strong>',
        esc_url( wc_logout_url() )
    );
    ?> -->
</p>

<p>
    <?php
    /* translators: 1: Orders URL 2: Address URL 3: Account URL. */
    // $dashboard_desc = __( 'From your account dashboard you can view your <a href="%1$s">recent orders</a>, manage your <a href="%2$s">billing address</a>, and <a href="%3$s">edit your password and account details</a>.', 'woocommerce' );
    // if ( wc_shipping_enabled() ) {
    //  /* translators: 1: Orders URL 2: Addresses URL 3: Account URL. */
    //  $dashboard_desc = __( 'From your account dashboard you can view your <a href="%1$s">recent orders</a>, manage your <a href="%2$s">shipping and billing addresses</a>, and <a href="%3$s">edit your password and account details</a>.', 'woocommerce' );
    // }
    // printf(
    //  wp_kses( $dashboard_desc, $allowed_html ),
    //  esc_url( wc_get_endpoint_url( 'orders' ) ),
    //  esc_url( wc_get_endpoint_url( 'edit-address' ) ),
    //  esc_url( wc_get_endpoint_url( 'edit-account' ) )
    // );
    ?>
</p>

<?php
    /**
     * My Account dashboard.
     *
     * @since 2.6.0
     */?>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_account_dashboard' );?>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-10 d-flex dashboard-custom">
        
<h4>Addresses</h4>
<div class="questionMark">
                                    <a href="#">?</a>
                         </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2 text-center pt-5 mt-2">
<a href="#" class="viwAdress">
    See
    
</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row pt-5">
    <div class="adress-dashboard">
        <div class="col-12 pt-4 d-flex">

<?php

$fname = get_user_meta( $current_user->ID, 'first_name', true );
$lname = get_user_meta( $current_user->ID, 'last_name', true );
$address_1 = get_user_meta( $current_user->ID, 'billing_address_1', true );
$address_2 = get_user_meta( $current_user->ID, 'billing_address_2', true );
$phonenumber = get_user_meta( $current_user->ID, 'billing_mobile_phone', true );
$city = get_user_meta( $current_user->ID, 'billing_city', true );
$postcode = get_user_meta( $current_user->ID, 'billing_postcode', true );



// echo $fname . "<BR>";
// echo $lname . "<BR>";
// echo $address_1 . "<BR>";
// echo $address_2 . "<BR>";
// echo $city . "<BR>";
// echo $postcode . "<BR>";

?>
<svg id="a47b7a8a-e7bb-4135-b65b-2487268cdcff" width="14" height="17" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 14 17"><defs><style>.b21eb9b6-977e-44fb-a0e8-fad7fb47a827{fill:#909298;fill-rule:evenodd;}</style></defs><path class="b21eb9b6-977e-44fb-a0e8-fad7fb47a827" d="M10.32,7.26A3.11,3.11,0,1,1,7.21,4.13,3.12,3.12,0,0,1,10.32,7.26Zm-1.55,0A1.56,1.56,0,1,1,7.21,5.7,1.56,1.56,0,0,1,8.77,7.26Z" transform="translate(0 -0.01)"/><path class="b21eb9b6-977e-44fb-a0e8-fad7fb47a827" d="M2.17,12.15a7.07,7.07,0,0,1-.24-10A7,7,0,0,1,11.83,2a7.07,7.07,0,0,1,.24,10L7.24,17Zm8.77-1.32-3.75,4L3.25,11a5.5,5.5,0,0,1-.19-7.75,5.42,5.42,0,0,1,7.69-.19A5.5,5.5,0,0,1,10.94,10.83Z" transform="translate(0 -0.01)"/>
</svg>
<h5><?php echo $address_1; ?></h5>
</div>

    <div class="col-12 d-flex pt-4">
    <svg id="bd6f5e62-b10a-4e71-b77c-d5f9368c28e6" width="14" height="17" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 11 18"><defs><style>.a30aed3e-ff50-49ef-a803-e1cfe573925c,.fa1d0d58-d038-41f3-bd11-17bb673b76c2{fill:#909298;}.a30aed3e-ff50-49ef-a803-e1cfe573925c{fill-rule:evenodd;}</style></defs><path class="a30aed3e-ff50-49ef-a803-e1cfe573925c" d="M9.17,4A3.84,3.84,0,0,1,5.5,8,3.84,3.84,0,0,1,1.83,4,3.84,3.84,0,0,1,5.5,0,3.84,3.84,0,0,1,9.17,4ZM7.33,4A1.92,1.92,0,0,1,5.5,6,1.92,1.92,0,0,1,3.67,4,1.92,1.92,0,0,1,5.5,2,1.92,1.92,0,0,1,7.33,4Z"/><path class="fa1d0d58-d038-41f3-bd11-17bb673b76c2" d="M9.17,12a1,1,0,0,0-.92-1H2.75a1,1,0,0,0-.92,1v6H0V12A2.88,2.88,0,0,1,2.75,9h5.5A2.88,2.88,0,0,1,11,12v6H9.17Z"/>
</svg>
<h5>Customer :<?php echo $fname ; ?> </h5>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 d-flex pt-4">

<h5>Phone :<?php echo $phonenumber; ?> </h5>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 d-flex pt-4">
    
<h5>ZipCode:<?php echo $postcode ; ?> </h5>
    </div>

</div>
<!-- adres box -->

</div>
<?php
    /**
     * Deprecated woocommerce_before_my_account action.
     *
     * @deprecated 2.6.0
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_before_my_account' );

    /**
     * Deprecated woocommerce_after_my_account action.
     *
     * @deprecated 2.6.0
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_after_my_account' );

/* Omit closing PHP tag at the end of PHP files to avoid "headers already sent" issues. */?>
</section>
```

---

And this is my Order template code that work on Orders Tab but don't work on dashboard Tab:

```
    <?php
/**
 * My Orders - Deprecated
 *
 * @deprecated 2.6.0 this template file is no longer used. My Account shortcode uses orders.php.
 * @package WooCommerce\Templates
 */

defined('ABSPATH') || exit;

$my_orders_columns = apply_filters(
    'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_columns',
    array(
        'order-number' => esc_html__('Order', 'woocommerce'),
        'order-date' => esc_html__('Date', 'woocommerce'),
        'order-status' => esc_html__('Status', 'woocommerce'),
        'order-total' => esc_html__('Total', 'woocommerce'),
        'order-actions' => '&nbsp;',
    )
);

$customer_orders = get_posts(
    apply_filters(
        'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_query',
        array(
            'numberposts' => $order_count,
            'meta_key' => '_customer_user',
            'meta_value' => get_current_user_id(),
            'post_type' => wc_get_order_types('view-orders'),
            'post_status' => array_keys(wc_get_order_statuses()),
        )
    )
); ?>

<?php if ($customer_orders) : ?>

    <h2><?php echo apply_filters('woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_title', esc_html__('Recent orders', 'woocommerce')); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped ?></h2>

    <table class="shop_table shop_table_responsive my_account_orders">

        <thead>
        <tr>
            <?php foreach ($my_orders_columns as $column_id => $column_name) : ?>
                <th class="<?php echo esc_attr($column_id); ?>"><span
                            class="nobr"><?php echo esc_html($column_name); ?></span></th>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
        <?php
        foreach ($customer_orders as $customer_order) :
            $order = wc_get_order($customer_order); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.WP.GlobalVariablesOverride.Prohibited
            $item_count = $order->get_item_count();
            ?>
            <tr class="order">
                <?php foreach ($my_orders_columns as $column_id => $column_name) : ?>
                    <td class="<?php echo esc_attr($column_id); ?>" data-title="<?php echo esc_attr($column_name); ?>">
                        <?php if (has_action('woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_column_' . $column_id)) : ?>
                            <?php do_action('woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_column_' . $column_id, $order); ?>
                        <?php elseif ('order-number' === $column_id) : ?>
                            <a href="<?php echo esc_url($order->get_view_order_url()); ?>">
                                <?php echo _x('#', 'hash before order number', 'woocommerce') . $order->get_order_number(); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped ?>
                            </a>

                        <?php elseif ('order-date' === $column_id) : ?>
                            <time datetime="<?php echo esc_attr($order->get_date_created()->date('c')); ?>"><?php echo esc_html(wc_format_datetime($order->get_date_created())); ?></time>

                        <?php elseif ('order-status' === $column_id) : ?>
                            <?php echo esc_html(wc_get_order_status_name($order->get_status())); ?>

                        <?php elseif ('order-total' === $column_id) : ?>
                            <?php
                            /* translators: 1: formatted order total 2: total order items */
                            printf(_n('%1$s for %2$s item', '%1$s for %2$s items', $item_count, 'woocommerce'), $order->get_formatted_order_total(), $item_count); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped
                            ?>

                        <?php elseif ('order-actions' === $column_id) : ?>
                            <?php
                            $actions = wc_get_account_orders_actions($order);

                            if (!empty($actions)) {
                                foreach ($actions as $key => $action) { // phpcs:ignore WordPress.WP.GlobalVariablesOverride.Prohibited
                                    echo '<a href="' . esc_url($action['url']) . '" class="button ' . sanitize_html_class($key) . '">' . esc_html($action['name']) . '</a>';
                                }
                            }
                            ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </td>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
<?php endif; ?>


  <?php
wc_get_template( 'myaccount/orders.php' ); 
?>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**No need to overwrite template files**, you can use the `woocommerce_account_dashboard` hook

Most of the code was copied from [myaccount/orders.php](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/683cc40cbf906eceb6ee1d91dcdaaa3e2c44df68/templates/myaccount/orders.php) template file,
here and there, however, there is an adjustment so that directly copying the template file is not a (complete) solution.

So you get:

```php
function action_woocommerce_account_dashboard() {
    // Set limit
    $limit = 3;
    
    // Get customer $limit last orders
    $customer_orders = wc_get_orders( array(
        'customer'  => get_current_user_id(),
        'limit'     => $limit
    ) );
    
    // Count customers orders
    $count = count( $customer_orders );
    
    // Greater than or equal to
    if ( $count >= 1 ) {
        // Message
        echo '<p>' . sprintf( _n( 'Your last order', 'Your last %s orders', $count, 'woocommerce' ), $count ) . '</p>';
        ?>
        <table class="woocommerce-orders-table woocommerce-MyAccount-orders shop_table shop_table_responsive my_account_orders account-orders-table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <?php foreach ( wc_get_account_orders_columns() as $column_id => $column_name ) : ?>
                        <th class="woocommerce-orders-table__header woocommerce-orders-table__header-<?php echo esc_attr( $column_id ); ?>"><span class="nobr"><?php echo esc_html( $column_name ); ?></span></th>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
                <?php
                foreach ( $customer_orders as $customer_order ) {
                    $order      = wc_get_order( $customer_order ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.WP.GlobalVariablesOverride.Prohibited
                    $item_count = $order->get_item_count() - $order->get_item_count_refunded();
                    ?>
                    <tr class="woocommerce-orders-table__row woocommerce-orders-table__row--status-<?php echo esc_attr( $order->get_status() ); ?> order">
                        <?php foreach ( wc_get_account_orders_columns() as $column_id => $column_name ) : ?>
                            <td class="woocommerce-orders-table__cell woocommerce-orders-table__cell-<?php echo esc_attr( $column_id ); ?>" data-title="<?php echo esc_attr( $column_name ); ?>">
                                <?php if ( has_action( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_column_' . $column_id ) ) : ?>
                                    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_column_' . $column_id, $order ); ?>

                                <?php elseif ( 'order-number' === $column_id ) : ?>
                                    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $order->get_view_order_url() ); ?>">
                                        <?php echo esc_html( _x( '#', 'hash before order number', 'woocommerce' ) . $order->get_order_number() ); ?>
                                    </a>

                                <?php elseif ( 'order-date' === $column_id ) : ?>
                                    <time datetime="<?php echo esc_attr( $order->get_date_created()->date( 'c' ) ); ?>"><?php echo esc_html( wc_format_datetime( $order->get_date_created() ) ); ?></time>

                                <?php elseif ( 'order-status' === $column_id ) : ?>
                                    <?php echo esc_html( wc_get_order_status_name( $order->get_status() ) ); ?>

                                <?php elseif ( 'order-total' === $column_id ) : ?>
                                    <?php
                                    /* translators: 1: formatted order total 2: total order items */
                                    echo wp_kses_post( sprintf( _n( '%1$s for %2$s item', '%1$s for %2$s items', $item_count, 'woocommerce' ), $order->get_formatted_order_total(), $item_count ) );
                                    ?>

                                <?php elseif ( 'order-actions' === $column_id ) : ?>
                                    <?php
                                    $actions = wc_get_account_orders_actions( $order );

                                    if ( ! empty( $actions ) ) {
                                        foreach ( $actions as $key => $action ) { // phpcs:ignore WordPress.WP.GlobalVariablesOverride.Prohibited
                                            echo '<a href="' . esc_url( $action['url'] ) . '" class="woocommerce-button button ' . sanitize_html_class( $key ) . '">' . esc_html( $action['name'] ) . '</a>';
                                        }
                                    }
                                    ?>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            </td>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                }
                ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <?php
    } else {
        ?>
        <div class="woocommerce-message woocommerce-message--info woocommerce-Message woocommerce-Message--info woocommerce-info">
        <a class="woocommerce-Button button" href="<?php echo esc_url( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_return_to_shop_redirect', wc_get_page_permalink( 'shop' ) ) ); ?>"><?php esc_html_e( 'Browse products', 'woocommerce' ); ?></a>
        <?php esc_html_e( 'No order has been made yet.', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_account_dashboard', 'action_woocommerce_account_dashboard' );
```

---

Code goes in `functions.php` file of the active child theme (or active theme).